# Why if condition work but else if condition doesn't work?

Tags: python, if-statement

I have been working on a project that uses a **`database`**. It makes the user choose from the commands in the program. The program makes you add your **password, E-mail,  user id, and birthday**, and every user has his own **user id**. He can make a **new user**, **delete password**, **delete user**, **change password and change user id**.

Every option has its own `command`, but there a problem appeared to me while I was working.

I made a input variable and named it **(Command option)** that prints a message which tells the user to write the command he wants to use,  I also made an If condition which is the variable **(Command option)** == "N" or "n" to create new user, and I made an else if condition that if the variable **(Command option)** isn't equal  "N" or "n" to print

("Sorry, we don't have this command"),

[My code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9FuT.png)

but the problem is that if I put the condition to make a new user before the condition ; to print,  doesn't work, even if the variable **(Command option)** isn't equal to "N" or "n", and if I do the opposite to put the condition to print before the condition to make a new user, the condition to make new a user doesn't work, even if the variable **(Command option)** equals "N" or "n" so, what's the problem?

> def create_new_user():
>
> ```
>   print(Fore.BLUE + "Please, Enter the following data so we could add it to the database: ")    
>
>   u_id = input(Fore.YELLOW + "user_id: ")
>   p_t = input(Fore.YELLOW + "password [text]: ")
>   e_t = input(Fore.YELLOW + "Email [text]: ")
>   b_t = input(Fore.YELLOW + "birthday [integer]: ")
>
>
>   cursor.execute("""
>   INSERT INTO data (user_id, password, Email, birthday)
>   VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)
>   """, (u_id, p_t, e_t , b_t))
>
>   db.commit()
>
>   print ('Data entered successfully.')
>
>   if (db.commit):
>
>
>      db.close ()
>
>   print("The connection is closed.")
> ```
>
> Command_option = input(Fore.YELLOW + "Please enter the command you
> want to use: ")
>
> if Command_option == "N" or Command_option == "n":
>
> create_new_user()
>
> else:
>
> raise Exception(Fore.RED + f"Sorry, we don't have this command :(")

Comment: `if variable == "N" or "n"` is testing whether `variable == "N"` is true, or if `"n"` is true. Python always considers a non-empty string to be true, so the overall condition is always true. I suspect you mean `variable == "N" or variable == "n"`, or `variable in ["N", "n"]`.

Comment: Please post code directly into the question, not a remote image of the code. People can help better if they can try the code on their own machine.